# Date Diff between same loop - php

Tags: php, date, intervals, datediff

I want to get the interval date between the same loop like shown in the above url 
[PHP - Calculate date between rows in a array loop (foreach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349407/php-calculate-date-between-rows-in-a-array-loop-foreach) 
Slightly different a bit because it does not get the first loop interval

Currently I use `date_diff`, but this only works if i got the different column like 

What if I want to count between the depart_date only, for instance

depart_date = 2019-12-24 - 0 day 
depart_date = 2019-12-25 - +1day 
depart_date = 2019-12-27 - +day2

That interval are the output I want, depart_date are the input I have in the looping
Is there way I can achieve using the date_diff only?

Comment: Please explain what you have (input), what you would like to get (output) and what you attempted. It may be explained in the other post, but you should make it clear in this one anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeto I have edited my explanation

Comment: Look into [DateInterval#days](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). A `DateInterval` is what `date_diff` returns.